# Add comments and attributes including an incremented number to elements in an HTML string

Tags: php, html, replace, html-parsing, preg-replace-callback

I have been trying to understand how `preg_replace_callback()` works, but I just don't get it.

Say for example, I get_contents from navigation.php.

In that text are a bunch of a href and divs and I want to give incremental ids to and add in some code commenting before each a href.

How would I loop over all those so they would all increment and add the ids and commenting?

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents("navigation.php");
$i = 1;
$replace = "<a ";
$with = '<!-- UNIT'.$i.' --><a id=a_'.$i;
$replace2 = "<div ";
$with2 = '<div id=b_'.$i;
preg_replace_callback()
$i++

?>
```

I figured maybe if I could get an example with my code, maybe I would be able to understand it better.

Do `$replace` and `$replace2` are my strings I am searching for and `$with` and `$with2` are the replacements respectively, and `$i` being the increment.

An example of data coming in:

```
<a href="page4.php">Page 4</a>
<a href="page3.php">Page 3</a>
<div class="red">stuff</div>
<div class="blue">stuff</div>
```

I would want an output like..

```
<!-- UNIT 1 --><a id="a_1" href="page4.php">Page 4</a>
<!-- UNIT 2 --><a id="a_2" href="page3.php">Page 3</a>
<div id="b_1" class="red">stuff</div>
<div id="b_2" class="blue">stuff</div>
```

Comment: If you hope to have answers, please add example strings and what you want to obtain.

Comment: I updated to reflect incoming and outgoing examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple goals, the simplest way to accomplish them imo is doing it step-by-step.

**1. The RegEx**

You want two HTML tags, these can be caught easily via `/(<a|<div)/i` ([explanation](http://regex101.com/r/uU4iT6), `g` modifier is only used to demonstrate that it correctly matches).

With this you could write the following code:

```
$parsed = preg_replace_callback('/(<a|<div)/i', ???, $string);
```

**2. The callback**

The logic behind this can be simplified to the following switch

```
switch ($found) {
    case '<div':
        $result = '<div id="b_'.$id.'"';
        break;
    case '<a':
        $result = '<!-- UNIT'.$id.' --><a id="a_'.$id.'"';
        break;
    default:
        $result = "";
        break;
}
```

---

To implement this you can either write a new function or use an anonymous one. To make `$id` accessible, you need to learn about [variable scope in PHP](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.scope.php). An easy way out of using anything like `global $id;` or `define()` is using [Closures](http://php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php) with the `use()` syntax. To be able to manipulate `$id` (increment it), you'll need to [pass it by reference](http://php.net/manual/language.references.pass.php) (when using Closures). This brings you to the following code:

```
$parsed = preg_replace_callback("/(<a|<div)/", function($match) use (&$id) {
    switch ($match[1]) {
        case '<div':
            $result = '<div id="b_'.$id.'"';
            break;
        case '<a':
            $result = '<!-- UNIT'.$id.' --><a id="a_'.$id.'"';
            break;
        default:
            $result = $match[1];//do nothing
            break;
    }
    $id++;

    return $result;
}, $string);
```

Watch it work [here](http://3v4l.org/YUFbq).

Comment: wow, thanks for the great example! that will help a lot. One more question on this, how would I include something with a wildcard aspect? take p tags for example...if I had <p id="joe" and <p id="will"  how could I add that into "/(<a|<div)/" so I could overwrite those with new values? like this maybe "/(<a|<div|<p id="*")/"

Comment: [`/(<a|<div|<p\s+id=".+")/`](http://regex101.com/r/jT8zS4) should work for this, you'll need to add this case to the switch then as well

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using a `preg_` function at all.  PHP has a robust set of tools for parsing valid HTML -- use a DOM parser.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ALmsS))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<body>
<a href="page4.php">Page 4</a>
<a href="page3.php">Page 3</a>
<div class="red">stuff</div>
<div class="blue">stuff</div>
</body>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$counter = 0;
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("a") as $a) {
    ++$counter;
    $comment = new DOMComment(" UNIT $counter ");
    $a->parentNode->insertBefore($comment, $a);
    $a->setAttribute('id', "a_$counter");
}
$counter = 0;
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("div") as $b) {
    ++$counter;
    $b->setAttribute('id', "b_$counter");
}
echo substr($dom->saveHTML(), 7, -9);
```

I have wrapped your HTML in a parent body tag and removed it at the end of the script to aid in preserving the newlines of your input (otherwise some newlines will be lost while processing).

The remainder of the the syntax is rather self-documenting because the class methods are very descriptive of their functionality.